# function out $('document').ready()

Tags: jquery

i've got this simple code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({
      success: function(id) {
         $('#ele').append('<a href="" onclick="deleteImg(id)">')
      }
   })

   function deleteImg(id) {
      foo...
   }

}
```

but, when i click on the created href, i received this error

```
deleteImg is not defined
```

i have to put the deleteImg function out the $(document).ready() to working it

why?

many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a string version of a function is called, like in `onclick="deleteImg(id)"` it executes in the global context, meaning it's basically looking for :

```
window.deleteImg
```

But it isn't there, it's only defined in your `document.ready` handler's scope.  You're better off binding the handler directly, like this:

```
$(function(){
   $.ajax({
      success: function(id) {
         $("<a href='#'></a>").click(function() {
           deleteImg(id);
         }).appendTo('#ele');
      }
   })
   function deleteImg(id) {
      //foo...
   }
});
```

Or, store it in data on the element if it's used for other things, like this:

```
     $("<a href='#'></a>").data('id', id).click(function() {
       deleteImg($.data(this, 'id'));
     }).appendTo('#ele');
```

Or, combine it all, and access it that way as well:

```
$(function(){
   $.ajax({
      success: function(id) {
         $("<a href='#'></a>").data('id', id).click(deleteImg).appendTo('#ele');
      }
   })
   function deleteImg() {
      var id = $.data(this, 'id');
      //foo...
   }
});
```

Comment: +1, (*but you need to escape your quotes or use single ones on the outside.., just nitpicking ..*)

Comment: @Gaby: Good catch, thought the coloring was off earlier but didn't process, fixed now

Answer (score 3):

```
function foo() {
    function bar() { alert("Hello!"); }
    var baz = 123;
}
```

In the above snippet, the `bar` function is a *local* function to `foo`. It's just the same as how the `baz` variable is a local variable to the `foo` function: you can't access `baz` outside of `foo` and you can't access `bar` outside of `foo` in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the scope. `deleteImg` is declared inside your anonymous `ready()` function and is not defined outside it.

Answer (score 1):

deleteImg is local to the function closure you're feeding $(document).ready(). Try this instead:

```
window.deleteImg = function(id) {
  foo...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could use jQuery to add the click event.

```
$.ajax({
   success: function(id) {
      $('#ele').append('<a href="" class="deleteImg">');
      $('.deleteImg').click(function() {
         window.deleteImg($(this).id);
      });
   }
})
```

It may look a bit overkill now, but if the code gets more complicated, or even the way it is now, it's usually a good idea to keep to Javascript and the HTML apart as much as possible. That's one of the main reasons to use jQuery in the first place.